# How can I make the Songs LaTeX package's index order be in Swedish?

Tags: indexing, songs

*I first posted this same question [over at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336345/how-can-i-make-the-songs-latex-packages-index-order-be-in-swedish), where someone informed me that Tex has its own Stack Exchange site.*

I'm making a song book in LaTeX, using the [Songs package](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html), and have been trying to find a way to get the index ordered according to Swedish alphabetical ordering (i.e. A-Z, then ÅÄÖ). The Songs package (or maybe LaTeX in general?) treats Å and Ä as simply A:s, and Ö as an O.

I build the index using the command

```
\newindex{mainindex}{register}
```

at the beginning of the book, before the actual songs, and

```
\showindex{Register}{mainindex}
```

at the end of the book.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You'll stand a higher chance of getting help if you provide a minimal working example, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.6.4 ("Sort Order") of [the package documentation](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html) describes how to adjust the sort order.  The procedure varies by operating system because your operating system decides the sort order as part of its "locale" setting.

For this to work, you must be sure to write the title/author texts in your .tex or .sbd files using unicode characters (e.g., using the "inputenc" package if necessary), not as LaTeX macros.